# No module named openai

Tags: python, visual-studio, openai-api

I've installed openai on my laptop with `pip install openai`.

Have installed on my laptop and after installed on the same folder where my code file is. But when I try to run the code I get `ImportError: No module named openai`

This is the code from the file. Pretty simple:

```
import openai

openai.api_key = API_KEY

prompt = "Say this is a test"

response = openai.Completion.create(
    engine="text-davinci-001", prompt=prompt, max_tokens=6
)

print(response)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of python installed on your machine - not a virtual environment?

Comment: how are you running this code?

Comment: No I have no virtual enviroment. I'm running it on VS

Comment: I've tried also with pip3 install openai. No success

Comment: @Zaesar you almost certainly are running you code in a different install of python than where pip is installing your packages. Assuming you are using pip in the terminal do `which python` or `where python` on widows to see if it is the same install of python you are using to run your code.

Comment: I get `/usr/bin/python` .Appreciate your help

Comment: And the file that I'm running is in `/Escritorio/coding/python$ `

Comment: @Zaesar make sure you are using the correct [python interpreter](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_work-with-python-interpreters) in VS Code. FYI - all Macs come with python2 installed by default so if you are not using `conda` make sure to use `pip3` and `python3`

Comment: I'm using Python select interpreter my python version Python 3.9.12. but still get the same `ImportError: No module named openai`.I can't figure out what is wrong

Comment: Selected different interpreters: the recommended `Python 3.9.12 64-bit`, `Python 3.6.9 64-bit` and `Python 2.7.17 64-bit` with thePython 3. it doesn't flag openai on file but with Python2 it flags it. Anyway trying all different ways I still get `ImportError: No module named openai`

Comment: When I write on the terminal python3 main.py (the name of the file) It works. It has to be something with VS but can't figure out what

Comment: I get this error too when running a python script that imports `openai` but not when I `import openai` in idle.

Comment: try with PyCharm instead - I also had the same issue in VS Code even when I created a new venv (strangely it ran for two runs and then went back to saying it didn't exist), install/uninstalled openai package

Comment: This solution might help with vscode editor - https://community.openai.com/t/no-module-named-openai/8303/3

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ModuleNotFoundError: No Module Named openai](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74311275/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-openai)

Answer (score 32):

I encountred the same problem and all what I did was:

First uninstall the openai package with :

```bash
pip uninstall openai
```

Then I upgraded pip with :

```bash
pip install --upgrade pip
```

And i re-installed the openapi package with

```bash
pip install openai
```

And it worked.

Comment: Saved my day! But how?

Comment: same here... new to python.. dont even know where pip came from lol

Comment: Good nugget of info here. Also using **macOS** and **python3** is the default.  So for me doing @clicmolette's idea and trying python3 for the commands helped

Answer (score 15):

This can happen if you have multiple versions of python

to show where pip has installed openai package, you can run this command

```
pip show openai
```

you will have an output like this

```
Name: openai
Version: 0.26.4
Summary: Python client library for the OpenAI API
Home-page: https://github.com/openai/openai-python
Author: OpenAI
Author-email: support@openai.com
License: None
Location: /home/${USER}/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages
Requires: requests, tqdm, aiohttp
Required-by:
```

as you see, for me pip installs the package openai for the python version 3.8.

so if the default python version is 2.7 for example, when running python then making **import openai**, this will not work.

you can change the default python version to the same verion of the package openai, use

```
sudo update-alternatives --config python
```

Then select the correct version (3.8 for me).

you can also try to install openai for your default python version:

```
python -m pip install openai
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Lots of answers sending me round in circles but this was the first one that helped diagnose and solve the issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your answer helped me. If anyone else is experiencing the same issue, please check that your Python version matches that of OpenAI.

Comment: This  was the  solution  to my problem as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Top answer didn't work for me, but this did:

I am using VS code on a mac. I had to select the correct Python interpreter. I am using Python 3 and pip3 instead of pip.

Uninstall the openai package with :

```
pip uninstall openai
```

Upgraded pip with (be sure to use pip3):

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

And i re-installed the openapi package with (be sure to use pip3):

```
pip3 install openai
```

Answer (score 1):

Try putting `--user` after the snippet.

```
pip install openai --user
```

After this, the error doesn't show up & the code works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

For the one who tries to run it on macOS (Please install [Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x) first), then use

```
sudo flask run
```

and it works.

Comment: flash is not a valid command on macOS.

Comment: @WebDev-SysAdmin My apologies, you need to go into the openai-quickstart-python and type 'sudo flask run'. Make sure for any dependencies for flask are installed

Comment: This was the solution that worked for me, and I hate it. (As of May '23, the OpenAI Quickstart tutorial seems well written and maintained, so it seems there must be some quirk of my setup that means I need to run flask under `sudo` where others don't, and one day I'll determine why.)

Comment: **sudo: flask: command not found**

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky Please remember to install Flask first: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/

Answer (score 1):

After you run the following command

```
pip install openai
```

If you are using visual studio code restart your kernal.it worked for me.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to run my openai python script through VS Code on a Mac with python3 installed. When I tried to run my script by pressing the play button supplied by VS Code's Pylance Python extension I kept getting the error message `No module named openai`.

What helped me was, to install openai with the standard prompt `pip install openai` and by executing my script through the terminal prompt `python3 script.py`.

Answer (score 0):

in case you are running the python script as admin (or sudo) it throws the error ImportError: No module named openai. but with out admin (or sudo) it just runs fine

Answer (score 0):

This might be a temporary VS code error. Try closing the app and trying it again. It worked well for me on pycharm.

I used this:

```
pip3 install openai
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone runs into this problem when running **Firebase** on an emulator:

You have to make sure this config is set to 'true' on pyvenv.cfg:

```
include-system-site-packages = true
```

Answer (score 0):

I did pip install openai on the macOS terminal at the root and the project worked afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

On your IDE , manually add the openai module to the interpreter .
The issue will be resolved !

For Pycharm ,

Go to File -> settings -> project -> python interpreter -> add the module (look for + symbol )
Tadaa !