# ModuleNotFoundError: No Module Named openai

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, interpreter

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import openai 

#write each line of nuclear.txt to a list
with open('nuclear.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

#remove the newline character from each line
lines = [line.rstrip() for line in lines]

#gather the text from each website and add it to a new txt file
for line in lines:
    r = requests.get(line)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    text = soup.get_text()
    with open('nuclear_text.txt', 'a') as f:
        f.write(text)
```

I'm trying to import openai, however it keeps throwing the error module not found. I have done pip install openai and it downloads, but it appears to be the wrong version of python. How do I select the correct one for pip to install to? I am using VSCode

pip install openai

Answer (score 11, accepted):

###### Follow the steps below to install the `openai` package for the current interpreter

1. run the following code

   ```py
   import sys
   print(sys.executable)
   ```
2. get the current interpreter path

   [image]
3. Copy the path and install `openai` using the following command in the terminal

   ```
   C:\WorkSpace\pytest10\.venv\Scripts\python.exe -m pip install openai
   ```

   *Modify the path in the above command to the interpreter path you got.*

   [image]

Comment: Worked for me on Mac: python3 -m pip install openai

Comment: This works when your python has multiple inconsistent versions. I made pip install openai work directly by going to my environment variables, deleting all python instances in the path, then deleting my python instances from program files and reinstalling python (ensuring that python is added to path during installation) This should fix the problem of needing to specify its location, as it is only needed when you have multiple python versions.

Answer (score 6):

Try using `pip3 install openai`, as it installs openai for python3, not python2 (if you have it installed). If you only have python3, pip and pip3 are basically the same thing (I think).

Comment: This did not work for me. Proper solution below

Answer (score 0):

The answer of JialeDu worked for me, but after I added the right path to my pip setting in the Environment Variables from windows

If you’d rather run pip (or other tools) from any location, you’ll need to add the directory in which it’s installed as a PATH environment variable by doing the following:

1 - Open up the Control Panel and navigate to System and Security > System
2 -Click on the Advanced system settings link on the left panel
3 -Click Environment Variables.
4 -Under System Variables, double-click the variable PATH.
5 -Click New, and add the directory where pip is installed, e.g. C:Python33Scripts, and select OK.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, when using the embeddings library from openAI. I kept adding the missing modules, and it worked until `sklearn`. What worked for me was:

```
pip install scikit-learn
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but I discovered that the package was being installed into a older python version's path. I installed the module by explicitly specifying the python version and that resolved the issue:

```
!pip3.11 install langchain
```

instead of

```
!pip3 install langchain
```