# Python installed in the wrong directory?

Tags: python, openai-api

(On Mac Chip: Apple M3 Pro)

I have Python installed in: /opt/homebrew/bin/python3 (that's what shows when I run which python3)
I have open ai installed in: /opt/homebrew/bin/pip3 (that's what shows when I run which pip3)

I am trying to run this code to create a chatbot:

```
import openai

openai.api_key = "###"

def chat_with_gpt(prompt):
    response = openai.chatCompletion(
        model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
        messages=[{"role": "user", "content": prompt}]
    )

    return response.choices[0].message.content.strip()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        user_input = input("You: ")
        if user_input.lower() in ["quit", "exit", "bye"]:
            break

        response = chat_with_gpt(user_input)
        print("Chatbot: ", response)
```

But i get:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openai'

Question: Is it the installation of Python and openai that causes the problem?

I have tried to install Python in another directory, but can't figure out how.

Comment: did you try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/74311332/11438227?

Comment: The answer is usually that you unknowingly have several python-interpreters on your system and use different ones for running your code and installing the packages. So (1) how do you start the script (2) how do you run pip

Comment: A good trick is to call pip as `python3 -m pip install <whatever>` and start scripts with `python3 <yourscript>`. That way, whatever `python3` is it will be the same in both commands.

Comment: Thanks! That link solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

No module named "X" basically tells you u haven't installed "X" module. So, you need to install openai module. You can install with using this command:

```
pip install openai
```