# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openai.openai_object'

Tags: python, llama, llama-index

I'm getting error while running a python script on macOS

> from openai.openai_object import OpenAIObject
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openai.openai_object'

How do I fix it?

```
(llama-py3.12) bash-3.2$ python3 starter.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/imac/ROOT/Python/chatgpt/llama/starter.py", line 1, in <module>
    from llama_index import VectorStoreIndex, SimpleDirectoryReader
  File "/Users/imac/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/llama-HG1XU64H-py3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/llama_index/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from llama_index.embeddings.langchain import LangchainEmbedding
  File "/Users/imac/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/llama-HG1XU64H-py3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/llama_index/embeddings/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from llama_index.embeddings.openai import OpenAIEmbedding
  File "/Users/imac/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/llama-HG1XU64H-py3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/llama_index/embeddings/openai.py", line 18, in <module>
    from llama_index.llms.openai_utils import (
  File "/Users/imac/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/llama-HG1XU64H-py3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/llama_index/llms/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from llama_index.llms.litellm import LiteLLM
  File "/Users/imac/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/llama-HG1XU64H-py3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/llama_index/llms/litellm.py", line 28, in <module>
    from llama_index.llms.litellm_utils import (
  File "/Users/imac/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/llama-HG1XU64H-py3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/llama_index/llms/litellm_utils.py", line 4, in <module>
    from openai.openai_object import OpenAIObject
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openai.openai_object'

(llama-py3.12) bash-3.2$ which python
/Users/imac/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/llama-HG1XU64H-py3.12/bin/python

(llama-py3.12) bash-3.2$ pip show openai
Name: openai
Version: 1.3.7
Summary: The official Python library for the openai API
Home-page: 
Author: 
Author-email: OpenAI <support@openai.com>
License: 
Location: /Users/imac/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/llama-HG1XU64H-py3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages
Requires: anyio, distro, httpx, pydantic, sniffio, tqdm, typing-extensions
Required-by: llama-index
(llama-py3.12) bash-3.2$
```

Comment: Maybe this one answers your question: [No module named openai](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71873182/no-module-named-openai)

Comment: My guess is that this is because of Python 3.12. It's a very recent python version and all data science libraries do not support it well yet. You should try with python 3.11.

Comment: @isa-Ali I've tried that answer, didn't work.

Comment: @Eskapp I started with 3.7, didn't work then tried with 3.12. I'll try with 3.11.

Comment: 3.7 is too old, there was not so so much genai back then ;)
I would try 3.10 (works on my machine and the Mac of coworkers) and 3.11
Actually it seems that this is the same issue here, resolved by moving to Python 3.10: https://community.openai.com/t/error-installing-openai-aiohttps-error-on-python-3-12/456052

Comment: @Eskapp Thanks man it worked with 3.10. Wasted my whole day figuring it out.