# Python 3.7 - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openai'

Tags: python-3.x, openai-api

**I am executing below Python 3.7 code:**

```
import openai

openai.api_key = "YOUR_API_KEY"

def get_completion(prompt, model="gpt-3.5-turbo"):
    messages = [{"role": "user", "content": prompt}]
    response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
        model=model,
        messages=messages,
        temperature=0,
    )
    return response.choices[0].message["content"]
```

**I am using Spyder IDE to execute the code.**

OpenAI installed is openai-1.6.1-py3-none-any.whl in path 'C:\Users\Hello\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\Scripts' which is added to PATH environment variable.

**Error I get in Spyder console:**
runfile('C:/Users/Hello/.spyder-py3/Prompt example.py', wdir='C:/Users/Hello/.spyder-py3')
Traceback (most recent call last):

File C:\Program Files\Spyder\pkgs\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py:356 in compat_exec
exec(code, globals, locals)

File c:\users\hello.spyder-py3\prompt example.py:7
import openai

**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openai'**

In what way do I resolve this error?

Executing Python using Spyder IDE to execute code. I get a runtime error. Need to get around the error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No module named openai](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71873182/no-module-named-openai)

Comment: `python -m pip install openai`